# How can I propagate exit status through a shell 'if' command in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

```
%/all:
    if [ -f $(@D)/src/Makefile ]; then \
        $(MAKE) -C $(@D); \
    fi
```

If the inner make fails, the outer make continues, presumably because the implicit exit status of the 'if' command is 0. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be a real example.  The shell will exit with the result of the last command executed, which if the if-statement succeeds will be the exit code of `make`, which is what you want.  So obviously in your real code, you must be doing some other command between the make and the end.  You can keep a copy of the result in a variable and use that as the exit:

```
if [ -f $(@D)/src/Makefile ]; then \
    $(MAKE) -C $(@D); \
    r=$$?; \
      ...do other stuff...; \
    exit $$r; \
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I couldn't reproduce your problem but I suppose the following should work for you :

```
%/all:
if [ -f $(@D)/src/Makefile ]; then \
    $(MAKE) -C $(@D) || (echo "make failure: $$?"; exit 1) \
fi
```